# how to use mutate and gsub together

Tags: r

I am using `mutate` and `paste` and `gsub` to write my code. is it a way I can write it in one chunk?

my codes are:

```
PMath <- PMath %>% mutate(MathALL = paste(MathMED, MathPR, MathACNOTH, sep = "; "))
PMath$MathALL <- gsub(pattern = "( ; )|(;  $)|\\.",replacement = "", PMath$MathALL, fixed = FALSE)
```

this code works. Now I rewrite it as:

```
PMath <- PMath %>%
 mutate(MathALL <- paste(MathMED, MathPR, MathACNOTH, sep = "; ") %>%
    gsub(pattern = "( ; )|(;  $)|\\.",replacement = "", ., fixed = FALSE))
```

and it won't work. What did I do wrong? Any way  to improve this?

Many thanks.

Sample data:

```
df<-structure(list(tst1 = c("Held", "Held", "Held", "Held", "Held", 
"Held", "Held", "Held"), tst2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Discont", NA, 
"Discont", NA, NA), tst3 = c(NA, "Med to treat : 10 Ondensetron, 12 Prochloroperazine", 
"Med to treat  : 10 Ondensetron, 12 Prochloroperazine", "Med to treat  : 14 Morphine", 
"Med to treat  : 13 Lovenex, 15 Apixaban, 11 Heparine", NA, NA, 
"Med to treat  : 21 Levaquin"), tst4 = c("1 Stent Placement", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The assignment should be `=` inside `mutate` instead of `<-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the assignment operator (`<-`) that is causing the issue.  We need `=` inside tidyverse functions.  Also, the data on the rhs of `%>%` would be `.`

```
library(dplyr)
PMath %>%
     mutate(MathALL = paste(MathMED, MathPR, MathACNOTH, sep = "; ") %>%
               gsub(pattern = "( ; )|(;  $)|\\.",
                replacement = "", ., fixed = FALSE))
```

---

It is a bit curious that the OP is creating a delimier (`;` ) and then removing it

In tidyverse, it can be also done with `unite`

```
 library(tidyr)
 PMath %>%
        unite(MathAll, MathMED, MathPR, MathACNOTH, sep="; ", na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: There are some "" and NA in value, so I have to remove the empty one with `; `.

Comment: @Stataq with `unite`, there is `na.rm` argument (updated)

Comment: When I tried `unite`, i got error message `Error in UseMethod("unite_") : no applicable method for 'unite_' applied to an object of class "NULL"`. also, should we use `=` or `<- `instead `%.%`  rhs of unite?

Comment: @Stataq The code is correct.  eg. `head(mtcars) %>% unite(amgearcarb, am, gear, carb, sep=";", na.rm = TRUE) %>% pull(amgearcarb)#
[1] "1;4;4" "1;4;4" "1;4;1" "0;3;1" "0;3;2" "0;3;1"`

Comment: Thanks. I must have sth wrong at somewhere. :P

Comment: @Stataq if you can show a dput of small example, it would make it easier to debug

Comment: I just add a sample data for my situation. I need to combine those cols in a nice way if it is possible. thanks.

Comment: @Stataq here, is the output I am getting `df %>% unite(tst5, tst1, tst2, tst3, tst4, sep=";", na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>% pull(tst5)
[1] "Held;1 Stent Placement"                                    "Held;Med to treat : 10 Ondensetron, 12 Prochloroperazine" 
[3] "Held;Med to treat  : 10 Ondensetron, 12 Prochloroperazine" "Held;Discont;Med to treat  : 14 Morphine"                 
[5] "Held;Med to treat....`

Comment: Why we have na.rm and remove? do we need `pull`?

Comment: @Stataq `remove = FALSE` is to prevent the original columns from getting removed, because by default, it is TRUE.  `pull` is just to extract as a vector to show the output here. `na.rm = TRUE` removes `NA` elements if there are any in each row (by default it is FALSE)

Comment: Thanks. When I run this code, I saw a lot " ; ; ;" in it. should i change the space to NA then remove them?

Comment: @Stataq In the example you posted, I didn't get a case like that even with lots of NAs.  I used `packageVersion('tidyr')#
[1] ‘1.1.2’`

Comment: @Stataq Can you check the output for the 7th element, which have 3 NA in that row `df %>% unite(tst5, tst1, tst2, tst3, tst4, sep=";", na.rm = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>% slice(7) %>% pull(tst5)#
[1] "Held"`. I have "Held" as the output

Comment: after I changed "" to NA, everything works as I want.

Comment: @Stataq oh yes, it is the blank (`""`) that caused it.  Thanks